# How can i deploy a Qt 5.10 Quick 2 application on windows xp?

Tags: windows, qt, visual-c++, windows-xp, mingw32

I installed Qt 5.10 Development Environment on my computer, where I had already installed Visual Studio 2017 with v141_xp toolset.

When I installed Qt 5.10, I selected the Mingw32 Tool Kit option.
Now, I have a QML application built using the Mingw32 build kit; this application uses some 3D feature (e.g. Bars3D, but it does not use angle).

I use the `windeployqt.exe` found in `\mingw53_32\bin` dictionary to deploy my application. That's works ok and can work in Windows 7.

However, **when I copy the deployed files onto Windows SP with SP3, it cannot run**;
I get an error like

> "cannot find the entry point xx in kernal32.dll..."

How can I deploy Qt 5.10 QML application for Windows XP using the VC compiler or using the Mingw or Alor? Or is there something else I need to know?

Comment: You should compile your application **and Qt** with toolset that supports Windows XP. `v141_xp tool set` is useless because you use mingw.

Comment: "xx" ??? is the name of a function right. Look up the function on MSDN and see if it is supported on XP. XP is ancient and not supported anymore.

Answer (score 0):

https://wiki.qt.io/PlatformSupport

5.6 is last official release that supports XP, but Im using 
Qt 5.7 VS2015 in Xp (but without webengine)